# Using echonest api jEN for Android project

Tags: android, api

I am trying to use the jEN library for a small project I have. I am new to android development so this may be something silly that I'm missing, but I've googled around and haven't figured out what the problem is.

I've added jEN and the json_simple jars to my build path and they are visible in Referenced Libraries of my android project. Everything seems to compile fine but upon running the app on an emulator, i get

> Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

there is no output from logcat. I've added the uses-library tags in the manifest, though it is unclear to me if that is actually necessary? Either way, I can't run without hitting this problem. Has this happened to anyone? Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: downloaded latest libs and added them to my own project's libs folder. still no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that removing the uses-library tags fixed the problem. Like I had mentioned, I wasn't sure if it was necessary in the first place. Funny thing is, I thought I had tried to run my app without the tags in the manifest file but I guess I didn't..